# Counting the frequency of a flush hand in $7$-card poker

Tags: combinatorics, poker

I'm trying to count the frequency of a flush hand in $7$-card poker. Since a flush hand could be thought of as having $5$ cards with the same suit while the other $2$ doesn't matter, I wrote down as follows. $$4\ _{13}C_{5}\ _{47}C_{2}=5564988$$ But this clearly is too much than the actual frequency of flush. What did I think wrongly?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey That's alternative notation for binomial coefficient.  [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) shows it as a "variation" of the notation, so ${}_nC_k=C(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to add the separate probabilities of an exact 5-card flush, an exact 6-card flush, and a 7-card flush. The probability is:
$$\frac{4\cdot_{13}C_5\cdot_{39}C_2}{_{52}C_7}+\frac{4\cdot_{13}C_6\cdot_{39}C_1}{_{52}C_7}+\frac{4\cdot_{13}C_7}{_{52}C_7}.$$

**Edit.** As @Logophobic pointed out in a comment, this answer is not quite correct, because it counts straight flushes as flushes. Assuming you don't want to count straight flushes, you have to subtract the probability of a straight flush.

Comment: It is also necessary to exclude any straight flush. The total number of flush hands in $7$-card poker is $4,047,644$. See [this reference](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/comp20/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with OP's original figure:

$$ {4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 7} \cdot {47 \choose 2} $$

is that it counts some flushes more than once. As an example, it counts both the following as distinct: 'A2345' + '67' all of hearts, and 'A2456' + '37' all of hearts, when they are actually the same hand.

This explains why we have to separately consider the cases where we choose 5, 6, and 7 of a suit